# For some reason, I can't use the Tkinter or tkinter module. After running the following command in the python shell

Tags: tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
```

output:

> AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Comment: Did you make a file with name 'tkinter.py'? If so, then rename it

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your python file? Check whether it is `tkinter.py` or `Tkinter.py`.

If the capital letter is the problem, you can change your line:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

to:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Comment: however this **shouldn't** be the case since You **shouldn't** use Python2.x since that version is deprecated, (unless You need to maintain something or sth)